# ReactJS - Keydown event . Preventdefault 229

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making text editor.
[This is demo image what i made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOZ3A.jpg)

Using contenteditable, I render code to dangerouslySetInnerHTML.
So the component look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9Lx3.jpg)

But like figure1, I can access next to select
( In second figure, it is between `</div> here <select ~~>`

I want to prevent a user from accessing and writing at that point
But I did not found preventing access method.

So I thought when user write content then check the parent and execute `event.preventDefault()` except for left arrow and up arrow.
it works well in English and others.
But when I write Korean. PreventDefault is not working.
How can I execute preventDefault in Korean??

```
handleKeyDown = (event) => {
  let key;
  if(window.event) {
    key = event.keyCode;
  } else {
    key = event.which; //For Firefox
  } 
  const selection = document.getSelection();
    if (selection.anchorNode) {
      const check = selection.anchorNode.parentElement;
      if (check.className.includes('src-components') && key !==37 && key !== 38) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        }
  }
}
```

- P.S : the event.target.value return undefined.